# is there an equivalent of the iPhoto faces feature for windows

Tags: windows, photos, iphoto

I need to find a whole bunch pictures of a couple of people in a large collection of photos on my PC. I have a couple of reference photos.

Is there an application with the equivalent of Apple's iPhoto - Faces feature on windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) works on Windows and has a similar feature.